# I want to verify my proofs.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

1).Prove: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^2-4}{n^2-4} = 3$. 
A proof: there exists an $\epsilon>0$. We define $N=\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil$ (notice $N>2$). So: 
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\frac{3n^2-4}{n^2-4}-3| < \epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\frac{3n^2-4-3n^2+12}{n^2-4}|<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow |\frac{8}{n^2-4}| < \epsilon  
\Leftrightarrow  \frac{8}{n^2-4}<\epsilon \Leftrightarrow\\ 8<n^2\epsilon-4\epsilon \Leftrightarrow \frac{8+4\epsilon}{\epsilon}<n^2 \Leftrightarrow  \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}<n. 
\end{aligned}
$$ 
This statement is true for all $n>N$,
because: $$\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}.$$
 thus, the limit is 3. $\Box$

2).$a_nb_n=1$. Prove or contradict: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=1$ so $\lim_{n\to\infty}|b_n|=1$.
This statement is true.
A proof: We choose $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, so:
$$
-\epsilon < a_nb_n-1 < \epsilon\Rightarrow -\epsilon+1<a_nb_n<\epsilon+1 \Rightarrow -\frac{1}{2}+1<a_nb_n<\frac{1}{2}+1 
\Rightarrow \\ \frac{1}{2}<a_nb_n<1\frac{1}{2} 
$$
Also:
$$
||a_n|-1|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} <|a_n| <1\frac{1}{2} 
$$
It's obvious that $a_n\neq 0$ for almost all n, otherwise $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.
If $a_n>0$ for almost all n, also $b_n>0$ for almost all n. we can divide and get:
$$
1<\frac{a_nb_n}{|a_n|}<1 \Rightarrow1<\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n}<1 \Rightarrow 1<b_n<1
$$
If $a_n<0$ for almost all n, also $b_n<0$ for almost all n. we can divide and get:
$$
1<\frac{a_nb_n}{|a_n|}<1 \Rightarrow1<\frac{a_nb_n}{-a_n}<1 \Rightarrow 1<-b_n<1
$$
And from the sandwich theorem we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}|b_n| = 1$. $\Box$

Comment: A small comment on format. It is sometimes beneficial to align $\Rightarrow$ and $\iff$ in a column if there are many of them in a chain, or using parentheses to group statements.

Comment: To detail what @shredalert was saying, use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` at the start and end of the `$$`. Then place a `&` before the object you want to align.

Comment: IMO it seems a little weird to prove IF and ONLY IF and to attempt to *prove* n > N rather than to start with n >N and work in one direct.  Also those steps *aren't* all iff.  $|8/(n^2 -4)| \ne 8/(n^2 -4)$ UNLESS  |n| > 2 which I guess you are assuming as $n > N$ but then ... you aren't proving n > N and that last step is unnecessary.

Comment: @fleablood At the end of the proof I wrote that this statement is true for all n>N, and at the beginning of the proof mentioned that N>2. I just found that starting with n>N is sometimes painful.

Comment: All these calculations just saying "this statement is true for all $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}<n$ ". So if we choose n>N, which is greater than 2 for almost all n, we get for sure a true statement.

Comment: Yeah, but I found it a little sylistically off-putting.  Leave off the $\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}$.  That really looks weird.  " I just found that starting with n>N is sometimes painful."  BUt not in this case.  And not if $N$ is well defined at the start.  Just my opinion.

Comment: Also $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4} < n \iff \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}$ is obviously not true. $\lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}$ no matter what $n$ is.  ...Or if you are doing all these if and only if statement under the assumption $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4} < n$ then $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4} < n \iff \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}$  reads something like $27 > 15 \iff 2017 $ is prime.  It's two statements that are simply universally true.

Comment: @fleablood "Also $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4} < n \iff \lceil{\sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}}\rceil \geq \sqrt{\frac{8}{\epsilon}+4}$  is obviously not true." I agree about that, I don't know why I chose to put it there. maybe it has its place in the closing statement.

Comment: I think you should simply say "If $n > \sqrt{blah}$ then ...... $|blah| < \epsilon$.  Straightforward and painless and easy to follow.  But, yes, your proof is good, I just feel.... it's a little stylistically obscure.

Comment: @fleablood I just love the idea that I can write everything once with the if and only if statements. No need for external sheets for calculations aside.I know the method you mentioned. the first step is to find the range for n, then define an N and put it in the limit definition to show its truthiness, but sometimes we don't see how to escape the painful expressions we might get. What do you think about the second proof? thanks.

Comment: @MorHaham Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to simplify note that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^2-4}{n^2-4} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n^2-12+8}{n^2-4} =\lim_{n \to \infty} 3+\frac{8}{n^2-4}$$

and we can show that eventually $0\le\frac1{n^2-4}\le\frac1n$ and $\frac1n\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you. In my case I had to prove it by the limit definition for homework. What do you think about the second proof?